# Listing the available properties / functions for Date in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to list the properties / functions for Date in JavaScript using the below code:

```
var mydate=new Date();
for(var i in mydate){
   console.log(i);
}
```

When I run the above code, nothing gets printed in console.

When I run the similar block of code for a object that I created
eg:

```
var emp=new Employee();
for(var i in emp){
   console.log(i);
}
```

I get results.

Please suggest if it is possible to list the properties / functions for Date, String, other native JavaScript types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Properties of date objects (or rather those that they inherit) are non-enumerable. Using [`Object.getOwnPropertyNames`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames) does reaveal them, so you can try this instead:

```
for (var o=new Date(); o!=null; o=Object.getPrototypeOf(o)) {
    console.log("on ["+o+"] itself:");
    Object.getOwnPropertyNames(o).forEach(function(p) {
        console.log(p)
    });
}
```

Alternatively, for checking the properties of native objects, you might just fire up their Docs - either [in the spec](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15) or [at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects). Also, simply `console.log`ging them usually produces an expandable view on an object that also includes the prototypes and their properties.

Answer (score 1):

Many built-in objects have their methods set to not be enumerable, and therefore won't show up in a `for..in` loop.

You should instead look up some [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date), and then you can test if your browser supports certain things like:

```
if( 'now' in Date)
```